# Possible to cancel a command that is queued to run, but that has not yet run?

Tags: r

I've got a script that will take a few hours longer to run.  Meanwhile, I open a different R script to work on something else.  I forgot to open a new R console tab (I use rgedit), and accidentally did `rm(list=ls())` from the second script.  I forget whether all of the relevant output from the long script will be saved, and I want to cancel the commands that are in the queue.  Is there any way to do this?

Here is a silly example that illustrates the point:

```
>x = "Something important"
>Sys.sleep(1000)
rm(x)
#Oh no!  I don't want to remove x!  How do I stop it before the command runs??!?
```

Comment: Press `ESC` to stop it.